# How do I make my decal non-transparent?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to make the label on this beer bottle non-transparent, but no matter what I try, light goes through it. As you can see from my node tree, it's just a decal applied with a diffuse shader. What am I missing? I need it to be totally opaque.

[image: Beer Troubles]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to **Add** both **Texture Image** and **Glass Shader**.

The thing you need to do is **Mix** both of them by **Mask**.

In below example I've used texture 2048x2048 with centered label and transparent background (PNG).

I don't know exactly how have you added your texture (and UV) so I can't describe precisely what should you do.

Feel free to add more information so I can extend my answer targeting your particular setup.

[image: Final]

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you! Working great now.