# transparent logo on glass

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm am making a bunch of liquor bottles and i have too much reflection on the transparent image on the outer part of the transparency.

My first material is the glass node,  my 2nd material is the transparent image on the section of the bottle I need it on.  I am thinking it needs to be all one material but i cant find the correct node set up if that is the case.

Do you have a node set up that will help him achieve less reflection.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52092/apply-texture-only-on-parts-of-object-with-nodes/

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38346/bottle-is-not-showing-up-clear-in-render-mode/38351#38351

Comment: And one from me: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79237/how-do-i-make-my-decal-non-transparent/79241#79241